# Material autocomplete selection by click

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

I have an autocomplete implemented, the autocomplete can receive suggestions and select suggestions by pressing enter. However, when clicking on an option, the options disappear without making the selection.

I have tried adding a (click) and other bindings to the options, but these methods are also not called.
Does anyone have an idea what the reason is that using enter to select works and clicking does not.

```
  <mat-form-field class="name" appearance="outline">
<input (change)="competenceChange()" placeholder="Competence name" matInput [(ngModel)]="competencePart.name"
  (ngModelChange)="this.competenceNameUpdate.next($event)" autocomplete="off" [matAutocomplete]="autoComplete">

<mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autoComplete="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let proposal of competenceProposals" [value]="proposal">
    {{ proposal }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
// Use the set debounce time to delay the execution of the search query.
// Every keypress resets the delay timer.
this.competenceNameUpdate.pipe(
  debounceTime(this.textboxInputDebounceTimeMS),
  distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(value => {
    this.obtainAutocompleteProposals(value);
  });


  private obtainAutocompleteProposals(value: string): void {
if (this.competencePart.name.trim() === '') { this.competenceProposals = []; return; }
this.competenceService.GetCompletionProposals(
  this.competencePart.type.valueOf(),
  value,
  response => {
    this.competenceProposals = response.completionProposals;
  },
  failure => {
    console.error(failure);
  });
```

It is important that the implementation supports the callback implementation which is used here as this is how our services are generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find complete example in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-autocomplete)

Make your input like this in your template file...

```
<input matInput placeholder="Select State" aria-label="State" 
                    [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl" (click)="getStates()">
```

and your autocomplete is..

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
            <span>{{ state }}</span>
        </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: I have seen this implementation, however I have seen no implementation which uses an async call to obtain the data. They all use a predefined list.

The function to obtain the data is in a generated service which uses a callback function to send the data back.